VSCodium not Recognizing Installed Libraries or pip/pip3 in Virtual Environment
I'm encountering an issue while working with VSCodium on Linux (Linux Mint). I've set up a virtual environment which VSCodium recognizes and activates. However, despite having installed Python3-pip, both pip and pip3 are not recognized within VSCodium. Consequently, VSCodium doesn't recognize the libraries already installed in the virtual environment, and it refuses to install further packages. Could someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.
